# regex: optional char (dot) when set, it must be everywhere in the string set

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, option-type

The . (dots) inside the following regex are optional (?).

Currently every single dot can be set or not. How is it possible to achieve that if one dot is set, every dot must be set.

```
/^([\d]{3}).?([\d]{4}).?([\d]{4}).?([\d]{2})$/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a capturing group with an optional dot inside after the first capturing group to capture the first dot (or its absence) and then use a `\2` backreference to that group instead of optional dots (note that they must be escaped to match literal dots):

```
^(\d{3})(\.?)(\d{4})\2(\d{4})\2(\d{2})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ltZbbb/1).

Note that capturing groups in the original regex will shift a bit starting with the second one (`(\d{4})` after `(\.?)` will have an ID of 3, and so on).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{3})` - Group 1: three digits
- `(\.?)` - Group 2: one or zero dots
- `(\d{4})` - Group 3: four digits
- `\2` - backreference to Group 2 value (either `.` or empy string
- `(\d{4})` - Group 4: four digits
- `\2` - backreference to Group 2 value
- `(\d{2})` - Group 5: two digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: amazing! thank you for your detailed explanation. Increased my basic understanding of regex.